# How to rebuild/reconfigure the HTTP Apache server after upgrading to PHP 7.0.* on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: command-line, server, upgrade, apache2, php

Previously I was using **PHP 5.5.32** on my system, everything was working fine. All the PHP programs and projects were running successfully.

Today, I upgraded to **PHP 7.0.4** and the trouble starts for me. Not a single 'Hello World' program is running, forget about the entire project.

Now if I type in the URL of a program in address bar to run in a browser(say"`http://localhost/hello.php`") I'm getting the PHP code as it is displayed in a browser, which was not happening previously when I was using **PHP 5.5.32**.

If I run the program from the command line(i.e. the terminal) I get the expected output which comes after execution of PHP code. I run the following command from the terminal and got the output.

```
$ cd /var/www
$ php hello.php
```

After googling a bit I came to know that Apache is the only issue responsible for this and for resolving it I have to "rebuild Apache" but no where I found how?

Can someone please help me in this regard please by providing me step-by-step detailed answer?

For reference and detailed understanding of the issue I'm facing you can refer the question below link :

[Why after PHP upgrade the program runs from command line but displays the PHP code as it is when run in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099079/why-after-php-upgrade-the-program-runs-from-command-line-but-displays-blank-web)

Comment: How did you install PHP 7?

Comment: @fkraiem: using only these two commands sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php and sudo apt-get install php7.0

Comment: Have you installed `libapache2-mod-php7.0` as well? If not, maybe your Apache PHP module is still on PHP 5 (you can see it with `dpkg -l | grep libapache2-mod-php`).

Comment: @fkraiem: No apart from above two commands I didn't run any other command to install any other thing. Can you please provide me the necessary commands to do the same? It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0`, what else?

Comment: @fkraiem:First of all thank you so much for your help. After executing the above command the PHP started working as previously it does. Just a small request from me. Could you please post it in Answer section so that I could accept it as an answer and it would be pretty much helpful to others as well? Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php7.0` package does not automatically install the Apache module of PHP 7, which is necessary to execute PHP scripts in Apache. It can be installed from the package `libapache2-mod-php7.0`.