# Unable to run PHP 7 in browser

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, php, php7

I have successfully installed PHP 7 using this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6iqiau-jLAhXHTY4KHbw0BRYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04&usg=AFQjCNE6TyDfcuFC-U6f64OXExSMYOI88g).

When I run following command in terminal

```
php -v
```

it successfully show that PHP 7 version detail.

But when I run a `test.php` file (made in web accessible folder and it has below content )

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

in browser like `localhost/test.php`
it still shows me my older version of PHP ie 5.5.9.

In browser every PHP script works fine but with PHP 5.5.9 not with PHP 7

And In terminal every PHP script works fine with PHP 7 but in browser, it works with PHP 5.5.9 not with PHP 7.

For example a file `ano_class.php` having anonymous class feature added in PHP 7  works as fine in terminal by following command

`php ano_class.php`

It successfully print expected results, but when I run the same file in browser like `localhost/ano_class.php` it gives me syntax error because anonymous class is not supported in PHP 5.5.9

I have done many research on internet but doesn't get the answer

Though I have referred many website, I referred  [here](http://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-ubuntu/) too.

How to get PHP 7 running in non CLI mode?

(I am using LAMP IN Kubuntu 14.04 )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rebuild/reconfigure the HTTP Apache server after upgrading to PHP 7.0.\* on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/747771/how-to-rebuild-reconfigure-the-http-apache-server-after-upgrading-to-php-7-0-o)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP rendered as text after Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760787/php-rendered-as-text-after-ubuntu-16-04-upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your webserver I am going to assume apache2 and will assume that you have

If you have php7 enabled in apache it should look something like

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ | grep php
php7.0.conf
php7.0.load
```

If you see php5 in there try

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-availible/ | grep php
```

If php7.0 is an availible mod you should be able to

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: what to do if php7.0 is not an available mod ?