# phpmyadmin installed but the page not rendered correctly by php

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have fresh installed apache, php7, mysql, and phpmyadmin, but when I chekout the localhost/phpmyadmin, seems like the page doesn't render by php like this.

```
ddJSON( 'list', PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) { PMA_printGitRevision(); exit; } echo '
'; } // Handles some variables that may have been sent by the calling script $GLOBALS['db'] = ''; $GLOBALS['table'] = ''; $show_query = '1'; // Any message to display? if (! empty($message)) { echo PMA_Util::getMessage($message); unset($message); } $common_url_query = PMA_URL_getCommon(); $mysql_cur_user_and_host = ''; // when $server > 0, a server has been chosen so we can display // all MySQL-related information if ($server > 0) { include 'libraries/server_common.inc.php'; include 'libraries/StorageEngine.class.php'; // Use the verbose name of the server instead of the hostname // if a value is set $server_info = ''; if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= htmlspecialchars($cfg['Server']['verbose']); if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ' ('; } } if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= $GLOBALS['dbi']->getHostInfo(); } if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose']) && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ')'; } $mysql_cur_user_and_host = $GLOBALS['dbi']->fetchValue('SELECT USER();'); // should we add the port info here? $short_server_info = (!empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose']) ? $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose'] : $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['host']); } echo '
' . "\n"; // Anchor for favorite tables synchronization. echo PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('favorite')->getHtmlSyncFavoriteTables(); echo '
'; if ($server > 0 || count($cfg['Servers']) > 1 ) { if ($cfg['DBG']['demo']) { echo '
'; echo '
```

etc, when I tried to create file test on var/www/html/test.php it rendered as text as well, I follow the instruction from internet, install via apt-get and set the apache.conf, am I missing something?

Comment: I found the answer from another ubuntu ask thread, that I need to install *apache2 SAPI* on *Ubuntu 16.04* by run command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php` http://askubuntu.com/questions/760787/php-rendered-as-text-after-ubuntu-16-04-upgrade , and sorry for dupplication