# Enabling threadsafe php7.0.8 with Apache2.4.18 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 (desktop) for LAMP

Tags: apache2, configuration, lamp, php7

I am new to ubuntu and would appreciate help overcoming a block setting up LAMP with software versions in this post's title (current I believe as of 11/2016).  **The problem seems to be an inability to configure Apache 2 with php7 mods.**

I am using default packages installed using "tasksel install lamp-server", but the downloaded Apache2 package did not seem to install as configured for php7 mods.  For example, the files "php7.0conf" and "php7.0load" were not copied into the folder "etc/apache2/mods-enabled".  Using "libapache2-mod-php7.0" also does not seem to enable php7.0 mods.  The only instruction I have found to enable php7.0 mods is "a2enmodphp7.0," which does copy the php7 "conf" and "load" files into Apache2's "mods-enabled" folder, but then Apache2 fails to restart with the following error:

"*Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.  AH00013: Pre-configuration failed

httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1*"

I get the same result downloading Apache2 individually (using "apt-get install apache2") followed by "apt-get libapache2-mod-php7.0" and "a2enmodphp7.0".

My research shows this to be a known incompatibility between Apache2 and php7.  A wiki on Apache says that Apache runs a threaded MPM while PHP7 is not compiled to be threadsafe.  It suggests a workaround using manual changes to Apache configuration files.  See Section 4.3 of https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP#PHP.

Before I start tinkering under the hood, **I would like to ask the community whether there is a more preferred solution?**  My trust in the people who put together the default packages leads me to hope they built in something that stitches them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to connect PHP to Apache. Those are called *server APIs* or *SAPIs*. To use the Apache module *mod_php* is one such SAPI. But some PHP modules (for example the MySQL module) can't handle working with multiple threads yet, they're not *threadsafe*. mod_php is a relatively tight coupling between Apache and PHP, so you can't use a threading MPM and not threadsafe PHP modules at the same time.

You've got two options: The first option is to switch to a non-threading MPM, being `prefork`. That would probably come with a performance penalty.

The second option is, switch to a SAPI that isn't as tightly coupled, like `fcgi` or `PHP-FPM`. These basically run as their own daemons, so the Apache MPM doesn't have to care if any modules in, say, the PHP-FPM daemon are thread-safe or not. But to set those up you need to do more than just install a package with `apt`, so there's a learning curve.

Comment: Thank you.  The solution for me was switching to Apache's prefork MPM using the following commands:

sudo a2dismod mpm_event followed by 
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork.

For the record, the following thread also has helpful information about this error and the FPM and CGI SAPIs:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/760787/php-rendered-as-text-after-ubuntu-16-04-upgrade?rq=1

Some other threads suggest that running libapache2-mod-php7.0 should accomplish the switch to Apache's prefork MPM module.  It didn't work for me, but the manual commands above appear to be successful.

Comment: @stuart_h Good to hear you solved your problem. If you think the answer was helpful, you can mark it as accepted :)